# Get ListView to "scroll past" RelativeLayout that's above it?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I wasn't sure how to phrase my question but that headline sort of explains it. I'll start off by saying that I'm really new to Android application programming.

My MainActivity consists of a RelativeLayout containing an EditText and a Button, and a ListView with a bunch of TextViews and some ImageViews in it. Now I've managed to place my searchbar- and button above my ListView, however I would like the search bar to not be constantly placed on top. I'd like it so that when I scroll in my ListView (which is displaying a bunch of posts, like a Twitter feed). Does anyone know if this is possible to achieve and if so - how?

I'll paste my activity_main.xml, the xml file for my ListView is really long and really only is a bunch of TextViews and such. (Can post on request though)

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:background="#cecece" >  

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:hint="@string/search_field" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/search_field"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:height="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:background="#bcbaba"
            android:text="@string/search_button"    
            android:onClick="searchQuery" />

    </RelativeLayout>   

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/dataListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_header" 
        android:paddingTop="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance, Kristina :)

Comment: At what point do you want the ListView to fill the entire area?

Comment: When scrolling down the ListView to view more posts. So basically I just want the search box to be on top of the ListView and then roll out of sight as soon as I start scrolling down. And to reappear when I scroll up to the top of the ListView again. @Mafro34

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any functionality of the `RelativeLayout` itself that will achieve this but what you could try is to programmatically set the visibility on the `EditText` to:
`.setVisibility(View.GONE)` which will completely "remove" it, which means the space it took will be free, or just `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` which will just make it invisible but will retain its space. To know when to call this on the `EditText` you can use an `onScroll` listener for your `ListView`.

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount) { 
//firstvisible is your first visible item in the list
}
```

To determine if your `ListView` is at the top or not you can use `firstVisible` above or 
`getFirstVisiblePosition()` and decide to make your `EditText` visible or not.

Hope this helps put you on the right track, I haven't actually tested it though.